# How can I render MathJax when some element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I have an input field in which I type LaTeX commands which must be rendered as MathJax when I click a button. I use the `textContent` property to set the content of the `div` element to whatever I type in the input field. However, the browser doesn't render MathJax and shows the content of `div` as LaTeX commands. I think this is probably because MathJax is rendered when the document is loaded. Is there some way by which I can render MathJax when the button is clicked? I have no knowledge of jquery or any other JavaScript library. Is there some way of doing this without using them or is it necessary to use them?

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
    <!-- The source is used to render mathjax -->
    function dispMJ() {
      var a = document.getElementById("mj").value;
      document.getElementById("disp").textContent = a;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="mj">
  <input type="button" value="render MJ" onclick="dispMJ();">
  <div id="disp"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the QUEUE to tell MathJax to rerender the div, Look a full example here http://codepen.io/damianfabian/pen/EgWEpv?editors=1000

```
UpdateMath = function () {
    var TeX = document.getElementById("MathInput").value;
    QUEUE.Push(["Text",math,"\\displaystyle{"+TeX+"}"]);
}
```